# mdadm array is active but is not listed

Tags: raid, mdadm

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04. I did apt-get upgrade and received a warning from mdadm.

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-24-generic
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md3 with UUID e3d153f0:6edf1702:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md1 with UUID 76492e25:648c4dcd:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
```

My current mdadm.conf is:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Tue, 11 May 2010 20:53:30 +0200
# by mkconf $Id$

ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3
```

The config generated by `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` is:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=76492e25:648c4dcd:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
ARRAY /dev/md3 UUID=e3d153f0:6edf1702:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
```

The warning says that /dev/md1 and /dev/md3 are not listed even though they are in the config. Is it okay change the config to the second one or will this cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I see is this line:

`#DEVICE partitions`

This is commented out in the generated config file but not yours. I'd just uncomment that and commit the changes. Warnings like that tend to be a "head's up" thing rather than an actual problem if the configurations line up.

Comment: Is there no difference between `ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1` and `ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=76492e25:648c4dcd:1f51fb89:78ee93fe` ?

Comment: Well okay, they're different, but `mdadm` can identify the arrays in more than one way. As long as the UUID is right, the array will work since it matches. That's why your line works (since `/dev/md1` is indeed made from your listed devices).